# Thank you for massive upvoting of my answers

Tags: discussion

This is not a question, I'm just saying thanks. Last night someone performed massive upvoting of 13 of my answers (most of them already accepted), thus giving me nice boost of 130 points.

I cannot find out who that was (even though I have my "suspects" ;-) ), and its not that important after all. I just want to say it boosts my confidence that I'm doing the right thing by helping fellow Joomlers, and that I will continue in doing so, regardless of getting points or not (but they do feel nice :-) ).

"All together as whole"... right?...

Take care y'all...

Comment: Hi Mirko, there's a clue at http://meta.joomla.stackexchange.com/q/261/120

Comment: Thanx Neil, I've suspected it... and as I said, my stance on JSE is only boosted by it...

Comment: Thanks for sticking around as a valued member of the community ;)

Comment: Always man, always... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Mirko, congrats, however I believe you have been serial upvoted. Not sure if this is something you have personally done or it's just bad luck.

It's happened to me before, and I've flagged my own account a couple of times to get it removed.

Another member sent me an email today flagging the reputation change and provided a good amount of evidence, backing it all up.

Comment: I dont know man, I've noticed that too, what sholud be done?

Comment: Already flagged to a moderator, so it's in their hands now

Answer (score 1):

Voting ethically AND not serial voting AND earning the [Suffrage Badge](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/badges/62/suffrage) is going to be trickier to do for me on JSX versus Stackoverflow.

I have sufficient expertise in general php/mysql topics to know if a post is upvote-worthy and there is a myriad of content on Stackoverflow.  With Joomla, I am very inexperienced and I'll need to be thoughtful about answers that seem to be flawless, helpful, and educational; and JSX has far fewer questions to choose from.  With fewer active posters on JSX, I'll need to be diligent that I am not awarding too many reps to any one user, because I don't want my votes to be reversed.

I think I will need to keep a stockpile of "great" questions and answers that I am willing to upvote and then do one big blast in a 24-hour period.

Now, I realize that the votes *may* be downvotes, but it is currently not in the best interests to "put down" posted content (when this site is out of its infancy, an "age of reckoning" will be called for to tighten up and weed out the suboptimal posts).

As I promote JSX in my Meetup group, I include discussion about badges.  Badges incentivize welcomed behaviors.  For the great majority of badges, you can't earn them without "doing good" within this community (of course, some people game the system -- this is unavoidable).